# How to avoid a trail of delegate calls in a navigation stack?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I've search result on View A. I've a filter options on search result. When suer clicks on filter view A it takes him to view B which lists all the filter options. Clicking on filters on B will take user to View C which shows selection for each filter. When user selects filters on view C I want to pass it back to A so that when user goes back to view A, after selecting filters, result data on A is updated after applying selected filter.

How to do that in any other simplest way possible?

Comment: We can't go from C to A directly.... we can go to A directly by calling `popToRootViewController()`  but .. in your case .. you want to send parameters to A .. right ?

Comment: Yes, I need to send parameters from C to A.

Comment: so its requirement to not call A from C ? you can push A again with those parameters ?

Comment: You can consider “coordinator” pattern. If you search for MVVM-C, you’ll see the idea outlined there.

Comment: Yes, I can't call C directly from A as it is the requirement. It has to be A -> B -> C. When we unwind (back button clicks) C -> B -> A. I've to capture some parameter and pass it to A. How to do that?

Comment: @Rob gave you an idea to search for `coordinator` pattern

Comment: or you can have a dataWrapper class

Comment: I didn't get dataWrapper class. Can you give me any link to study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. I will share the easiest. Create a modal struct, update its value from view controller C and then use it in A.

```
 struct StudentData { 
    static var name = ""
    static var address = ""
 }
```

In View Controller C, update the values

```
StudentData.name = "your name" 
StudentData.address = "your address"
```

In View Controller A,

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    nameField.text = StudentData.name
    addressField.text = StudentData.address
}
```

Comment: Is it a real code? Will it work? I don't see any variable of type StudentData?

Comment: Sorry ignore above comment. I understand what you are saying. In my case the parameter I want to pass is structure itself. How to handle that?

Comment: struct Name {
    var name: String?
    var isPresent: Bool?
}

var nameArray = [Name]()

Comment: make them `static var` and you are good to go... you can use it in your ViewControllerA as shown above.....